# Kafka Streams Punctuation Timestamp ahead of context timestamps

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We're working with a custom Transformer which makes use of STREAM_TIME punctuations. When I log messages coming through the transform function the stream time from context.timestamp() shows as expected - sane dates based on the data derived using the timestamp extractor.

Now - sometime in the past we had some rogue messages which pushed the stream time ahead to 2036. We have now stopped these upstream, and restarted Kafka Streams.

When streams starts, the punctuator runs on start up for the affected task, but shows a timestamp of 2036 - even though as messages come through transform, context.timestamp still show valid dates.. As a consequence, the stream never advances and the punctuator never runs again. Example of how I derive timestamp in punctuation is below...

```
 override def punctuate(timestamp: Long) : Unit = {

      val currentTimeStamp = timestamp
```

Comment: Some logs: When the punctuator runs (at start up only, the log shows the timestamp) -  Stream ordering Punctuator: Executing for task 4_30: Current:2086007292029 However, in the transform function running for the same task id, the timestamp is completely different - stream ts=1635778876000

Comment: The punctuator seems to run on kafka streams startup before it has even processed any messages - yet it has the stream time of 2086007292029. How can this be? Is there some state somewhere I cannot find? We run the cleanUp function before starting streams also...

Answer (score 1):

OK - after doing what I should have done and pored through Kafka Streams code, it became apparent that the stream times for partitions are held in the metadata which is persisted in _consumer_offsets. Application Reset Tool was the way to 'reset' this data.